# Are there any ways to track mobile phones like shown on television?

Tags: privacy, phone, geolocation

Are there really some ways to get the Geo-Location of a mobile phone? I've seen in many TV crime shows (like "Sawdhan India" and "Crime Patrol") where the Police Force catches a criminal through obtaining their location through their mobile phone. A criminal calls a person, the person gives the number to the police (or sometimes the police were tracking their number), and if they get the number of the caller, they trace the location. Is this possible?

Comment: Only if you play Angry Birds.... #Sarcasm http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jan/27/nsa-gchq-smartphone-app-angry-birds-personal-data

Comment: Yes. This is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile phones connect through cell towers operated by telephone companies. By simply looking up what towers the mobile phone is connected to, the phone company can determine where they are.

In some countries, special tracking stations are set up (last year, Russia put in such stations in subway stations), so that the police can track individuals.

Comment: Ok, this looks possible, but my Question was'nt much clear, i mean the exact x.y Position in the world like the GPS, But Technically i think for this the Mobile Phone should send them the Location, is'nt it? But they Shows that the Criminals were last located in this place, before this market, Do mobile phones are programmed for this? Or this is completly FAKE??

Comment: I dont know if theres really any Special Tracking Solutions applied in our Country(INDIA) but i think, NOPE!! but they still shows it, i think its completly Fake, its just for Viewers Imaginations...